# dynamic form with input and select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need an form with possibility to add new row consisting SELECT and INPUT. This works for me, but when I submit form no variable from SELECT is posted.

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<button id='add'>Add</button>
<form action="test.php" method="get">
<div class='container'>
    <select>
    <option name='service[]' value=1>HDD Recovery</option>
    <option name='service[]' value=2>PC Clean</option>
    <option name='service[]' value=3>Other</option>
    </select>
    Description<input type='text' name='desc[]'>
    Price<input type='text' name='price[]'>


</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var removeButton = "<button id='remove'>Remove</button>";
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('div.container:last').after($('div.container:first').clone());
        $('div.container:last').append(removeButton);
        $('div.container:last input').each(function(){
           this.value = ''; 
        });

    });
    $('#remove').live('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('div.container').remove();
    });
});
</script>
<br>
</html>
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Form elements must have a ***NAME*** and a value to be submitted. Add a name to the select element.

Comment: Issue is, that 'desc' and 'price' from INPUTs are submited, but 'service' is not.

Comment: ....did you even read the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to name the select, not the options it holds.

```
<select name="service[]">
    <option value="1">HDD Recovery</option>
    <option value=2>PC Clean</option>
    <option value=3>Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: THX - that was the problem. I feel like an i*iot now; -)

Comment: then please take the time to up+accept the answer ;) and don't worry, stuff that makes you feel like an i*iot happens, no matter how experienced you are...

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<select name='service[]'>
```

instead of giving name to **option**

```
<option name='service[]' value=1>HDD Recovery</option>
```